# How to track clicks outside the custom view

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, custom-view

I've a custom view, it looks so

[image]

How can I track click on the white space (outside the view) and hide it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

U can use `touchesBegan` to track it like so:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch= [touches anyObject];
    if ([touch view] == self.view)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

For swift:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        if let touch = touches.first {
            if touch.view == self.view {
                // do stuff
            }
        }
        super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent:event)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `UIView` under the Custom View covering the whole screen, give it an alpha of 0.1 or so. You can then add a `tapGestureRecognizer` to it to catch all the touches outside the custom view.

Just remember to hide the overlay too when you hide the custom view, so that the touches are not blocked afterwards.